# How can I solve the error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'jupyterhub'

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, centos, jupyter, jupyter-lab

I am trying to get JupyterHub installed and configured on CentOS 7 but I am getting the following:

```
Feb 12 18:28:10 hostname.org jupyterhub: [I 2020-02-12 18:28:10.826 JupyterHub log:174] 302 POST /hub/login?next= -> /hub/spawn (meuser@172.69.69.69) 309.19ms
Feb 12 18:28:11 hostname.org systemd: Started Session c9 of user meuser.
Feb 12 18:28:11 hostname.org jupyterhub: [I 2020-02-12 18:28:11.302 JupyterHub spawner:1417] Spawning jupyterhub-singleuser --ip=10.10.10.10 --port=51914 --NotebookApp.default_url=/tree/home/meuser
Feb 12 18:28:11 hostname.org jupyterhub: Traceback (most recent call last):
Feb 12 18:28:11 hostname.org jupyterhub: File "/usr/local/bin/jupyterhub-singleuser", line 7, in <module>
Feb 12 18:28:11 hostname.org jupyterhub: from jupyterhub.singleuser import main
Feb 12 18:28:11 hostname.org jupyterhub: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'jupyterhub'
Feb 12 18:28:11 hostname.org jupyterhub: [I 2020-02-12 18:28:11.986 JupyterHub log:174] 302 GET /hub/spawn -> /hub/spawn-pending/meuser (meuser@172.69.69.69) 1016.77ms
Feb 12 18:28:12 hostname.org jupyterhub: [I 2020-02-12 18:28:12.080 JupyterHub pages:347] meuser is pending spawn
Feb 12 18:28:12 hostname.org jupyterhub: [I 2020-02-12 18:28:12.087 JupyterHub log:174] 200 GET /hub/spawn-pending/meuser (meuser@172.69.69.69) 15.77ms
Feb 12 18:28:20 hostname.org jupyterhub: ERROR:asyncio:Task exception was never retrieved
Feb 12 18:28:20 hostname.org jupyterhub: future: <Task finished coro=<BaseHandler.spawn_single_user() done, defined at /opt/jupyterhub/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/jupyterhub/handlers/base.py:741> exception=HTTPError()>
Feb 12 18:28:20 hostname.org jupyterhub: Traceback (most recent call last):
Feb 12 18:28:20 hostname.org jupyterhub: File "/opt/jupyterhub/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/jupyterhub/handlers/base.py", line 939, in spawn_single_user
Feb 12 18:28:20 hostname.org jupyterhub: timedelta(seconds=self.slow_spawn_timeout), finish_spawn_future
Feb 12 18:28:20 hostname.org jupyterhub: tornado.util.TimeoutError: Timeout
Feb 12 18:28:20 hostname.org jupyterhub: During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Feb 12 18:28:20 hostname.org jupyterhub: Traceback (most recent call last):
Feb 12 18:28:20 hostname.org jupyterhub: File "/opt/jupyterhub/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/jupyterhub/handlers/base.py", line 972, in spawn_single_user
Feb 12 18:28:20 hostname.org jupyterhub: % (status, spawner._log_name),
Feb 12 18:28:20 hostname.org jupyterhub: tornado.web.HTTPError: HTTP 500: Internal Server Error (Spawner failed to start [status=1]. The logs for meuser may contain details.)
Feb 12 18:28:40 hostname.org jupyterhub: [W 2020-02-12 18:28:40.341 JupyterHub user:692] meuser's server never showed up at http://10.10.10.10:51914/user/meuser/ after 30 seconds. Giving up
Feb 12 18:28:40 hostname.org jupyterhub: [E 2020-02-12 18:28:40.390 JupyterHub gen:599] Exception in Future <Task finished coro=<BaseHandler.spawn_single_user.<locals>.finish_user_spawn() done, defined at /opt/jupyterhub/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/jupyterhub/handlers/base.py:845> exception=TimeoutError("Server at http://10.10.10.10:51914/user/meuser/ didn't respond in 30 seconds",)> after timeout
```

I followed these instructions on installing JupyterHub on CentOS 7: [Install Jupyter](https://jupyterhub.readthedocs.io/en/stable/installation-guide-hard.html) not using Conda, using pip and NPM. There was a similar issue reported here: [GitHub 2276](https://github.com/jupyterhub/jupyterhub/issues/2276) and the only conflicts I have is when I run the command `head -n 1 $(which jupyterhub)` that reports `#!/bin/python3` and when I run the command `which -a python3` I get `/usr/bin/python3`. Is this an issue? If so, how can I fix this?

Comment: It seems that there are two different installation of python3.6 /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages and /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages and I cannot rectify this

Answer (score 0):

This error was popping up because the permissions on the site-packages directory were 700. The solution to this was recursively adding read and execute permissions for all to the `/opt/jupyterhub/lib64/python3.6/site-packages` directory.